# Ensure caption remains under image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to ensure that when the screen in resized smaller the caption under the image does not disappear which is currently happening.

Any help/ direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

```css
#containerr {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: justify;
  min-width: 600px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

#containerr div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

#containerr:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerr">
  <div>
    <a id="single_image1" href="#">
      <img src="example.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px" />
    </a>
    <p> hello this is a world </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a id="single_image1" href="#">
      <img src="example2.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px" />
    </a>
    <p> hello this is a world </p>

  </div>

  <div>
    <a id="single_image1" href="#">
      <img src="example3.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px" />
    </a>
    <p> hello this is a world </p>
  </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Can you put this in a plunkr?

Comment: It probably took you more time to write this comment, than to make a plunkr, jsfiddle, codepen or whatever yourself - [anyway here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/cy21LLka/)

Comment: @MarcHjorth - Your solution doesn't. It simple displays the caption on top of the image... plus the images are uneven once screen is larger enough...

Comment: It wasn't a solution, I just put your code in a jsfiddle, so people don't have to complain :) @zeduke

Comment: @MarcHjorth - I see, I apologise, thank you.

Comment: @information_interchange - Marc beat me to it but here it is in plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/2VZH1Pghhihn2XBSR6X1?p=preview

Comment: @zeduke made an answer, not sure if that's what you want, otherwise you have to eloborate a bit :)

Comment: Nevermind the answer, I don't know why your text is disappearing, can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Your solution did work on the JSFiddle and was exactly what i was looking for, but for some reason when I try to implement on my end it wouldn't work..

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your captions are disappearing is because of the `inline-block` in your `containerr div` CSS reference. To solve this for example you can just make it `block` which will show your captions like so:

```css
#containerr {
padding-top:30px;
height: 300px;
text-align: justify;
min-width: 600px; 
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;

height: 100%;
margin-left:  100px;
margin-right:  100px;
}

#containerr div {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
display: block;
background: red;
}

#containerr:after {
content: '';
width: 100%; 
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerr">
<div>
<a id="single_image1" href="#">
    <img src="example.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px"/>
</a> 
<p> hello this is a world </p>
</div>

<div>
<a id="single_image1" href="#">
    <img src="example2.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px"/>
</a> 
<p> hello this is a world </p>

</div>

<div>
<a id="single_image1" href="#">
    <img src="example3.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px"/>
</a>
<p> hello this is a world  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

I would however recommend that you reorganize your HTML elements to get the most desired appearance.

Also, unrelated but **very important** is that you cannot use the same `id` on multiple elements as you have done with your `a` tags. If you want them all to have the same style, use `class` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution has not work for me.. It will still only display the one caption at the bottom while the other two are hidden under the image

Answer (score 0):

Now its displaying your caption under the image.

here is the preview:[preview image of image caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W1Q9.jpg)

Try to test this code into your Browser.

```css
#containerr {
padding-top:30px;
height: 300px;
text-align: justify;
min-width: 600px; 
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;

height: 100%;
}
#containerr div p{ position: relative;}

#containerr div {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
display: inline-block;
background: red; margin:50px auto;
}

#containerr:after {
content: '';
width: 100%; 
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerr">
<div>
<a id="single_image1" href="#">
    <img src="example.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px"/>
</a> 
<p> hello this is a world </p>
</div>

<div>
<a id="single_image1" href="#">
    <img src="example2.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px"/>
</a> 
<p> hello this is a world </p>

</div>

<div>
<a id="single_image1" href="#">
    <img src="example3.jpg" alt="" width="400px" height="300px"/>
</a>
<p> hello this is a world  </p>
</div>
</div>
```